# Show column titles in HorizontalHeaderView

Tags: qt, qml, qtableview

I am trying to create a simple QML Table view, based on a static model.  While I have that working, I can't get my column titles to display.  What displays now is "1", "2", "3" etc.  But I want to show the column titles as defined in my model.

I would like to use HorizontalHeaderView (since that is the NEW way to use titles).  Can someone point out how to fix my code below?

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    
    TableModel {
        id: myModel
        TableModelColumn { display: "companyName" }
        TableModelColumn { display: "info1" }
        TableModelColumn { display: "info2" }
        rows: [
            {
                companyName: "company 1",
                info1: "company 1 info 1",
                info2: "company 1 info 2"
            },
            {
                companyName: "company 2",
                info1: "company 2 info 1",
                info2: "company 2 info 2"
            },
            {
                companyName: "company 3",
                info1: "company 3 info 1",
                info2: "company 3 info 2"
            }
        ]
    }
    
    TableView {
        id: myTableView
        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true
        
        model: myModel
        
        delegate: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 50
            border.width: 1
            Text {
                text: display
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
    
    HorizontalHeaderView {
        id: horizontalHeader
        syncView: myTableView
        model: myModel
        //        model: [ "A","B","C"]
        delegate: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 50
            Text {
                text: display
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One approach is to create your own model in C++ or python and override the function `headerData` that will provide header name based on index. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#headerData

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue a few days ago. Apparently, you have to specify the model also in HorizontalHeaderView, i.e. the column titles.

This way it worked as expected for me. I hope it answers your question.

```
    TableModel {
    id: myModel
    TableModelColumn { display: "companyName" }
    TableModelColumn { display: "info1" }
    TableModelColumn { display: "info2" }
    rows: [
        {
            companyName: "company 1",
            info1: "company 1 info 1",
            info2: "company 1 info 2"
        },
        {
            companyName: "company 2",
            info1: "company 2 info 1",
            info2: "company 2 info 2"
        },
        {
            companyName: "company 3",
            info1: "company 3 info 1",
            info2: "company 3 info 2"
        }
    ]
}

TableView {
    id: myTableView
    anchors.fill: parent
    clip: true

    model: myModel

    delegate: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 100
        implicitHeight: 50
        border.width: 1
        Text {
            text: display
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}

HorizontalHeaderView {
    id: horizontalHeader
    syncView: myTableView
    model: [ "companyName","info1","info2"] // HERE column titles
    //        model: [ "A","B","C"]

    delegate: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 100
        implicitHeight: 50
        Text {
            text: modelData // HERE point to model
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}
```